# The "right" proof for derivative of stationary distribution of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $P$ be an irreducible Markov matrix, and $\pi$ its stationary distribution. Let $D$ be a perturbation matrix which is zero except for two entries in row $r$:
$$D_{rg}=+1 \qquad D_{rf}=-1.$$
Let $\widetilde{P}(\delta)=P+\delta D$. This is a small perturbation where transitions happen a little more to the gaining state $g$ and a little less to the falling state $f$.

In [1], Conlisk derived using results of [2] the following remarkable formula for the effect on the stationary probability of the gaining state:
$$ \frac{d}{d\delta} \pi_g(\delta) = \pi_r\frac{m_{fg}}{m_{gg}}.$$
Here $M$ is the mean first-passage time matrix, with $m_{ij}$ defined to be the expected number of steps, when the chain starts at $i$, that it takes to first visit $j$ after that.

Conlisk's proof [1], and Schweitzer's calculations that underlie it, use the fundamental matrix of the chain. **But it seems that such a simple formula should have a fairly simple, and probabilistic, proof**.

Does anyone know one?

[1] Conlisk, J., 1985. Comparative statics for Markov chains. Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control, 9(2), pp.139-151.
[2] Schweitzer, P.J., 1968. Perturbation theory and finite Markov chains. Journal of Applied Probability, 5(2), pp.401-413.